# Getting a blank result pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.3.4

So here is my dataframe that I'm working with:

```
First name  Last Name
Freddie     Mercury
John        Lennon
David       Bowie
Joseph
            Jovi
```

I would like a result of `df["Full name"] = df["First name"] + df["Last name"]` to produce a result even if it does not have both the first and last name column filled.

so `df["Full name"]=`

```
Full name
Freddie Mercury
John Lennon
David Bowie
Joseph
Jovi
```

This is my current code and does not produce a result if either a first name or last name is missing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str, header=0)

df["Full name"] = df["First name"] + " " + df["Last name"]

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

This is currently producing:

```
Full name
Freddie Mercury
John Lennon
David Bowie
```

Comment: You can use `df.fillna("")` because it will not merge nan data, so you must convert it to an empty string this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pandas Fill Nan Values With Empty String

You can replace the nan values with a blank string so that it will include them when running your concatenation program. For example:

```
df.fillna("")
```

Include this just after you have read from your file and before you use your code. This can also be applied to individual columns.